# Why doesn't AVPlayer work with a URL found with FileManager?

Tags: swift, macos, url, avplayer

If I use a file URL fetched with NSOpenPanel, creating an AVPlayerItem and replacing AVPlayer:s current item with that works fine. But if I fetch the same file URL with FileManager, AVPlayer won't open the file, even though no errors are generated. I even made a '==' comparison of the file URL:s for debug purposes and it evaluates to true (the same file URL fetched with NSOpenPanel and fetched with FileManager).

I'm fetching the file URL:s of videos in a directory and then populating a NSPopUpButton with the names of the video files. Selecting a video from the NSPopUpButton should load that video into AVPlayer, but this is not working even though the URL:s that I'm passing to AVPlayerItem are correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: You aren't supposed to open any file you want to use without user's consent.  That's basics for developing Cocoa apps.

Comment: That makes sense El Tomato. But here the user chooses a directory from where the NSPopUpButton is populated with video file names. When the user chooses a file from the NSPopUpButton the file is loaded. From the users perspective, he is giving consent to opening the file. How to tell the system that?

Comment: The idea is that the user can filter the file list in the app and the NSPopUpButton with the video files gets updated according to the filtering.

Comment: That's your idea, not Apple's idea.  Their idea is such that you let the user select a file with NSOpenPanel.

Comment: So there is no way to implement what I want?

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxing prevents opening files that have not been opened with NSOpenPanel. Removing the Sandbox slice from project target capabilities by clicking the X, removes this restriction.

As I am creating a program for my own use, removing sandboxing is not a problem. I don't know if and how it affects AppStore eligibility.